# Pattern matching and replacing based from regex

Tags: r, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to parse through a string and modify values that match a particular pattern. I am basically trying to convert the following R code into Python.

```
sample_formatted <- stringr::str_replace(sample, 
                      '(\\b[a-zA-Z]+):([a-zA-Z]\\b)', '\\1\\2')
```

I am completely new to Python regex and a struggling to figure out where to start.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) would be a good place to start. Then also this [demo site](https://regex101.com/) allows you to play with patterns and see their calculations live with explanations

Answer (score 1):

I guess then you can simply do a `re.sub` in Python:

```
import re

regex = r"(\b[a-zA-Z]+):([a-zA-Z]\b)"

test_str = ("abc:x\n"
    "DEf:y\n"
    "ABC:z")

subst = "\\1\\2"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/NyN1rj/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The visualizing tool will definitely help a lot.